# Multiproccesing and lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, multiprocessing

I have a list of jobs but due to certain condition not all of the jobs should run in parallel at the same time because sometimes it is important that a finishes before I start b or vice versa (actually its not important which one runs first just not that they run both at the same time) so i thought i keep a list of the currently running threads and when ever a new on starts it checks in this list of currently running threads if the thread can proceed or not. I wrote some sample code for that:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square_and_test(x):
    print(running_list)
    if not x in running_list:
        running_list = running_list.append(x)
        sleep(1)
        result_list = result_list.append(x**2)
        
        running_list = running_list.remove(x)
    else:
        print(f'{x} is currently worked on')

task_list = [1,2,3,4,1,1,4,4,2,2]
running_list = []
result_list = [] 
pool = Pool(2)
pool.map(square_and_test, task_list)
print(result_list)
```

this code fails with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'running_list' referenced before assignment` so i guess my threads don't have access to global variables. Is there a way around this? If not is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach to the problem. If you need them to wait for computations I think it would be better to use a producer/consumer pattern.
Also, are your computations idempotent? in that case you just need to cached them somehow. Just throwing some ideas here.

Comment: you are right this is a much better solution (producer/consumer pattern)